# Is it possible to link two different list

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to link two different mutableListOf and get proper-> default value with the use of-> key while using mutableMapOf
like i tried on the basic level but I was unable to do that

```
fun main() {

    val enginerName = mutableListOf("Mark", "Bill", "Jeff")
    val website = mutableListOf("Facebook","Microsoft","Amazone")
    val google = mutableMapOf(enginerName to website)

}
```

One more thing i try to get -> key directly but unable to do that because i linked two list.

Comment: `engineerName.zip(website).toMap()`

Comment: Pairing and MapOf working same or did they have some difference as of now i write few programs they have same fun to call as well as function the same

Comment: A Map can only have one value per key, and lets you retrieve values by key. A list of Pairs has neither of those features.